# No puedo instalar MySql.Data en Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, mysql, referencias

estoy trabajando en la actualización de consultas sql de un proyecto, para el cual tengo los siguientes productos instalados

[image: productos]

Debo usar Visual studio 2010 ya que el proyecto utiliza Telerik y solo tenemos la licencia compatible para visual studio 2010, es por eso que uso MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.3 ya que es el único disponible para visual studio 2010, al momento de cargar el proyecto debo agregar la referencia MySql.Data pero solo me aparece MySql.Data.Entity ¿es lo mismo? o ¿hay alguna forma para que pueda agregar MySql.Data?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En Visual studio 2019 si me deja agregar MySql.Data pero lo necesito en Visual Studio 2010, soy nueva en todo esto y se me complica mucho, espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Intente dercargar e instalar NuGet para visual studio 2010 pero me sale ese error ¿saben cómo solucionarlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: estas en framework 4 (no importa tanto el visual studio). Descargaste por nuget el paquete que necesitas para eso?

Comment: Hola @gbianchi es que en visual studio 2010 no me aparece la opción de Administrar paquetes NuGet, simplemente doy clic derecho en References>Add References y me muestra la segunda imagen que agregué en mi pregunta

Comment: ah puede ser pq es muy viejo... y no tendras que bajar el paquete a mano para tu framework?

Comment: igual fijate si no lo podes agregar.. googlea nuget visual studio 2010

Comment: Hola @gbianchi descarge NuGet para visual studio 2010 pero al momento de querer descargar MySql.Data me genera el error que adjunte en una imagen en mi pregunta ¿sabes a qué se debe? he investigado un poco y dicen que puede deberse a que es una versión viejita de NuGet ¿Crees que haya algún problema si instalo una versión reciente de NuGet en Visual studio 2010?

Comment: Es que se supone que la versión de NuGet que instalé solo trabaja con visual studio 2010 y 2012, creo que no podría usar una reciente :c ¿alguna idea?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113171/discussion-between-ana-and-gbianchi).